# shiny r ddply Object not found error

Tags: r, plyr, shiny

I'm running into Object not found issue with ddply in shiny server.R code
Here is what I have

```
    a1<-read.table("orig_final.txt", header = T) 
    shinyServer(function(input, output) {
    data <- reactive({
    ddply(a1, .(Claim_type),here(summarize), size_in_GB sum(eval(parse(input$bygroup))))
    })
    })
```

input$bygroup value is coming from user selection in the checkbox group named "bygroup" and it's values are the column names in data frame a1.
The error I got was Object "input" not found
Why is it not taking the input$bygroup value?

Comment: Can you provide more context? Where is the shinyServer function?

Comment: Here is some more information on where ddply is called :

Comment: Server.R code `code` a1<-read.table("orig_final.txt", header = T) shinyServer(function(input, output) {data <- reactive({ddply(a1, .(Claim_type),here(summarize), size_in_GB = sum(eval(parse(input$bygroup))))})})

Comment: I can't answer my own question, but this solved the problem : By changing text=input$bygroup inside the parse did the trick. 
By the way the error "Ojbect input not found" occured when I didn't have "here" around summarize, the error without text= was "connection not found"